# how to refer to a specific part of html from different parts of a web page

Tags: html

I have been working hard on assembling photos into a travel blog. Currently I am reading about how to make full page image carousels. The specific problem I have is this: I want to have an image carousel of 100 pictures. At different points in the blog I want the user to be able to enter the same carousel at different images in the sequence. Currently I have to duplicate the code for the 100 images at each point in the blog. I am trying to figure out how to refer to the same html from different parts of the web page. Here is an example:

https://bwanaaa.github.io/flicktest/

The first image is a full bleed cover. The next two galleries are the same gallery but different starting points. I had to list all 10 images in the html TWICE to achieve this. You can imagine how verbose the html gets if i have 50 images with 10 entry points.

Here is a codepen to experiment with:

http://codepen.io/littleredbowtie/pen/yNdOMQ

Is there a way to have a 'subroutine' in html?

Comment: You could use javascript to clone the html so you only have to write it once. Or you could use server-side code (such as PHP) to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be resolved through HTML alone. You'll have to implement further JS functionality, or find a different plugin.

Here is a plugin that is closer to what you're looking for:
https://github.com/stylehatch/photoset-grid

Demo:
http://stylehatch.github.io/photoset-grid/

it makes a grid of photos, then you also add the lightbox functionality, whatever photo they click on, it will go to that photo in the photoset, and also have navigation icons comparable to a carousel.

Comment: thank you but the presentation is a little cumbersome-i do not want all images showing up at the outset - i prefer the carousel the way flickity implements it. I'll keep looking.